# PHP exec returns ascii characters

Tags: php, exec

I want to display the PHP version on my page, and I have two PHP binaries on my server.
One is used for the website (i.e. used by the content in /public_html/) and the other one is used by the command line.

Both the PHP have different version so I want to display the CLI PHP version using the web server. I have the path of both binaries.

I am using:

```
exec('/usr/bin/php-cli -r "echo phpversion();"', $phpversion, $ret);
echo $phpversion = implode('', $phpversion);
```

But it is giving me some ascii code which is not recognized by my browser.

The out put I get is `�2�3�34��V.B`

What's going wrong?

Comment: why don't you use "php-cli --version" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. This issue was coming because zlib.output_compression was turned on.
I just turned it off and it resolved the problem.
Thanks for the replies guys.

Answer (score 0):

Its a characterset issue.

Before sending any output to your browser do:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Your browser has, as I see it, another default as UTF-8. 
When I run your code I get `"5.4.6-1~dotdeb.0"`

Comment: I have charset as utf-8 but than also it is giving me the same issue.